# Angular bind to svg text element getting unknown property error

Tags: angular, svg

I'm trying to bind a value to an SVG/Text element's dx property. Without binding it would look like:

```
<svg width="100%" height="130px" viewBox="0 0 150 150" *ngIf="!filled">
  <circle attr.stroke='{{backColor}}' stroke-width="5" fill='transparent' r="50" cx="50%" cy="35%" />
  <text x="50%" y="32%" dx="8" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="33" attr.fill="{{color}}">{{value}}
  </text>
  <text x="50%" y="45%" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12" attr.fill="{{color}}">{{label}}
  </text>
</svg>
```

I've tried various binding possibilities like:

```
<text x="50%" y="32%" dx="{{dxnum}}" >
```

and

```
<text x="50%" y="32%" [dx]="dxnum" >
```

But this always gives an error saying that dx is not a recognized attribute of SVG text:

Can't bind to `dx` since it isn't a known property of `:svg:text'. ("lor}}' stroke-width="5" fill='transparent' r="50" cx="50%" cy="35%" /> <text x="50%" y="32%" [ERROR ->]dx="{{dxnum}}" alignment-baseline="middle"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since there are no corresponding property binding on `svg` element, use `attribute` binding instead of `property` binding. See [Attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding) docs

```
[attr.dx]="dxnum"
```

Comment: Fastest answer ever! Thanks!

Comment: @IhorKhomiak my pleasure that my answer helped you, thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar how to set viewBox values dynamically?